# When switching routes in angular 4, app gets slower, nr of nodes keeps increasing (in chrome, not in firefox)

Tags: angular, performance, google-chrome, garbage-collection, angular-routing

When I switch routes several times, the app gets slower.  When I enable chrome debugger and look for 'performance + memory', I see the nr of nodes increasing.

It appears that the dom nodes are not destroyed when switching routes.

My component listens to an ngrx store, but unsubscribe is in place, change detection is onPush. I deploy with production = true (enableProdMode())

In firefox, I don't have this issue.  Probably it's a plugin in chrome that reserves these dom elements?  When I close the debugger, the problem remains.

Installed plugins in chrome: redux, augury, ...  But even when debugger is closed, the problem occurs.

Can you manually trigger garbage collection?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this was because we were not cleaning up the store when the view is unloaded. You might want to try cleanup things in the components destroy event handler.

In any case profile the application using chromes allocation times lines and you can see what is holding on to the objects which are not garbage collected.

Update:
We had deregister the rxjs observables in ngdestroy event.